# has_post_thumbnail gives always TRUE

Tags: post-thumbnails

I am using this code in my template:

```
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
    the_post_thumbnail(array(80,80));
} else {
    ?>
    <img src="http://example.org/<?php the_title(); ?>" width="80px" height="80px" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
    <?php
} ?>
```

its supposed to post an image in case the featured image is not present but it doesnt, like if it always detects a featured image even when there is none. So I guess has_post_thumbnail() is always giving true.

How can I fix this? Or maybe there is an alternative to detect whether or not there is a feature image present?

Thank you.

Comment: What does it output when you load an image that's not supposed to have a post thumbnail/featured image? And what kind of loop is this inside?

Comment: As mentioned in the [codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_post_thumbnail/):  "It’s worth noting that `has_post_thumbnail()` does not just check for the Featured Image as the Codex User Contributed Note suggests. If a post contains no defined featured image but it does contain an image in the content this function will still return TRUE."

Comment: It outputs nothing and its inside `while ( have_posts()`. Also, the post contains no image at all.

Answer (score 3):

Then you're using it outside of the loop, try this instead:

```
<?php
if (has_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID() )) {
    get_the_post_thumbnail( get_the_ID(), array(80,80) );
} else {
    ?>
    <img src="http://example.org/<?php the_title( get_the_ID() ); ?>" width="80px" height="80px" alt="<?php the_title( get_the_ID() ); ?>">
    <?php
} ?>
```

If you're not inside of a WP_Query loop, then post-specific functions like `has_post_thumbnail()` `the_title()` won't work unless you explicitly pass a the unique-id of a post/page to them.

Comment: It is inside `while ( have_posts()` but its not working. If the featured image is present it displays that but if not then nothing its displayed.

Comment: Why are you using `img src="http://example.org/<?php the_title(); ?>"` in the else? How would that ever map to an image? Is the title of the post/page the same as an image which resides at the root of your website?

Comment: its a little more complex than that but yes, its about that.

Comment: By the way, I managed to make it work though I am aware it might not be the best solution  `ob_start(); the_post_thumbnail(); $ass = ob_get_contents(); ob_end_clean(); if ($ass!=null) { the_post_thumbnail(array(80,80)); } else`

Comment: Nice :) `$ass = get_the_post_thumbnail(); if(!empty($ass))` might avoid the need for buffering.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that it will immediately post the thumbnail upon declaring the variable.

Comment: not with the get prefix. that's the difference between get_the_title & the_title. get_the_something just grabs the value and can be assigned to a var, whereas just the_something will self-echo. It's a common pattern throughout programming, not just WP :)

Comment: You are right. It works better that way. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome, happy to help.